# Field 'x' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql

I got an error `CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'editedbyid' doesn't have a default value.` The SQL statement executed was:

```
INSERT INTO `pos` (`serialnumber`, `posmodelid`, `active`, `created`, `updated`, `forapproval`, `approvedbyid`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, 1, NOW(), :yp2, :yp3, :yp4)"
```

I'm using MySQL, PHP and uii framework. How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 12):

The field `editedbyid` in your database table doesn't have a default value configured.

So, when inserting a new row, the database engine doesn't know which value it must set for the `editedbyid` field.

possible solutions are:

**1. set a default value:**

With phpmyadmin for example, select the `pos` table, enter a default value for the 'editedbyid' field.

**2. insert a value for the 'editedbyid' field:**

```
INSERT INTO `pos` (`serialnumber`, `posmodelid`, `active`, `created`, `updated`, `forapproval`, `approvedbyid`, `editedbyid`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, 1, NOW(), :yp2, :yp3, :yp4, 0)"
```

**EDIT**: Also read [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558260/what-is-the-default-value-for-a-field-if-no-default-value-is-provided) about default values.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe Try running SET GLOBAL sql_mode='' or edit your my.cnf to make sure you aren't setting STRICT_ALL_TABLES or the like.
Yii issues