# How do I leave a field unspecified during a PDO INSERT?

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a MYSQL table for users that holds a field for phone,

[image]

If I do an insert (using PDO) and don't specify phone, I get the error:

> Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field
>   'phone' doesn't have a default value

I've tried changing the Default with phpMyAdmin to NULL, but hpMyAdmin won't take that as a default. If I delete the phone field it just goes on to report the same error for the next field I'm not specifying, streetAddress.

So how can I set this up so MySQL will not complain if I put in a new record without specifying certain fields?

Comment: PDO has nothing to do with this error, mind you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Field 'x' doesn't have a default value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733266/field-x-doesnt-have-a-default-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the second to last column in your screenshot is the "allow NULL" one. Since it's set to **no** for phone, you aren't allowed to set the default value to NULL. If you switch that to **yes** first, it should work fine to set the default value to NULL after that. Compare with `ct_password` which has default value NULL.

That should sort out your issues I believe.

Comment: Yes, indeed.  The column in phpMyADmin says "Null" which I misunderstood to mean "set it to Null,"  not "Allow Null." Thanks. I'm curious why someone would downvote this question.