# MySQL NOT NULL insert behavior

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.5

I am currently working with a MySQL 5.5 and want to upgrade to 5.6 or 5.7. 
However I ran into strange behavior (may be mysql bug or some global default variable).
Following code works fine with 5.5, but doesn't work with 5.6, 5.7.
So either 5.5 has an issue or I am missing some settings with 5.6/5.7.

```
create table null_test( not_null VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);
insert into null_test values();
```

As expected, following doesn't work.

```
insert into null_test values(NULL);
```

Based on some early digging, it might have to do with the SQL MODE, especially ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-full

Comment: Probably could simply be solved by explicitly giving the field a default value.

Comment: I understand how to solve it. But I am trying to understand why it is happening. Also there is a large existing application that is running against 5.5. Just can't change every single query to test against new version of mysql. I know it is the pain I have to go through but it is not the solution at the moment.

Comment: You don't need to change the application. Just change the table column to have `DEFAULT ''`

Comment: I meant when migrating the database to the newer server version, the table definitions could be updated to specify defaults. My guess is that there is probably some obscure server setting/option for defaulting nulls to an empty string on non-nullable varchar fields, but am thinking it might be faster to just update the schema. Chances are if such an option was added, and defaulted to that state, MySQL is either migrating away from that implied behavior or possibly new optimizations are making that the preferred behavior.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558260/what-is-the-default-value-for-a-field-if-no-default-value-is-provided?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a result of [Strict SQL mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict) being enabled by default in the newer MySQL versions.

When Strict mode is disabled, omitting a value for a column that's declared `NOT NULL` and doesn't have an explicit `DEFAULT` value produces a warning and assumes an automatic default. For `VARCHAR`, this automatic default is an empty string.

When Strict mode is enabled, this condition causes an error unless you use `INSERT IGNORE`.

There's no specific SQL mode that just controls this behavior; if you want to turn off this check, you'll need to disable Strict mode entirely. Since Strict mode is likely to produce other incompatibilities (e.g. `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` errors), this may be the most expedient way for you to handle the migration.

But if you just want to deal with this specific error, the best solution is to declare an explicit default in the schema:

```
create table null_test(not_null VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '');
```